# Using Comparator

Tags: switches, relay, comparator

I have a comparator: [AD8651](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8561.pdf) that I am trying to use to switch on my relay (relay is rated at 5V). I have a 5V supply that I am using and I am just using a function generator to see the response.  For this situation I am "comparing" to 2.5 V and my function generator is going at 100 Hz from 0 to 5 (I have this set up on a breadboard on my desk).

I am trying to figure out the proper use of the hysteresis and load.  So I tested my relay and it has ~30 Ohm resistance between it so I put a 30 Ohm resistor on my output, and when I do that, my 5V does nothing.  The comparator just spits out 0 V (well actually like 20 and 50 mV).

If I use a large load, like 100k (or 1 MOhm on the termination of scope)then I get 0 and 3.8V.  But with the load that drops to zero.  I am kind of assuming that my supply cannot draw enough power to handle the 30 Ohm load?  Can I compensate with the hysteresis?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjOcGG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Your comparator can't supply enough current for the relay. You can only get about 3mA from the comparator so you will need to add a transistor to activate the relay. It's still possible that your power supply can't provide enough current but you didn't give enough information to comment on that.

Comment: My supply is 5V and up to 3A, so I thought I would be alright, but seems like not.  I do have a transistor around here, so I will do that.  Thanks

Comment: The supply's 3A rating is the limit it can provide. It does not mean the comparator itself can pass through the same 3A. If it can, I don't think it would do so for very long.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong comparator:

This one is high speed 10mA

5V relay is possibly 80 mA.

Also you have it wired wrong.

See answer : [Non-TTL debouncing](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/140952/non-ttl-debouncing)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think it's a bad idea to switch a relay at 100 or 1kHz. The contacts will wear out very quickly. Instead, you can use a transistor.

Generally speaking, OpAmps are unable to drive relays, so we use driver IC, such as [ULN2003](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/uln2003a.pdf). This can solve the problem, assuming that your power supply can provide the power needed.

Also, Analog provides in page 8 of the datasheet, a way to utilize a hysteresis loop. They mixed up inverting and non-inverting inputs, but you can get a good idea for how to implement it.

Comment: I wasn't actually switching the relay, just looking at the output on a scope with a 30 Ohm load.  As for the reason I am using the Op Amp, it is what we have around, so I am just trying to design something from that.

Comment: My bad, I misunderstood the part where you said you put a 30Ω resistor. 

In any case, like everyone said, it is not possible to drive the relay with this OpAmp. You have to use a transistor, a driver or an other OpAmp. 
And see page 8 of the datasheet, where they present a hysteresis configuration.